# Post apocalyptic movie with people living underground

Tags: identify-this-movie

I can not remember the movie title, but I am trying to find it for maybe 2 years. I am remembering only few scenes, could you please help me?

The scenes are these, or so:

1. It is a post apocalyptic movie with an environmental disaster theme. The air is unbreathable or there is a big amount of radiation on earth's surface.
2. All men and women are living somehow separated in (probably) underground shelter but they talked to each other via videophone.
3. Two of them fall in love and try to escape, despite going out from shelter to the surface is prohibited.
4. They live separated in there 'cells' and have big screen on front wall which they are using to video calling themselves. As they run on the running belt, the video image on the wall was projected as they run in the nature, probably on the shore. they secretly meet in the ventilation shaft or in some tunnel.
5. They decide to escape together, because some old man told them that the atmosphere is ok now, or it was something like that.
6. They escape through ventilation (probably) which ends on the shore with shipwreck (?) or something rusty.

The movie was probably from the 80's or 90's, not necessarily an English/American production.

It is not Logan's Run, The Island, Cherry 2000, THX-1138 nor the clonus horror...

Comment: Is it The Island with Ewan McGregor and Scarlett Johansson? From 2005...

Comment: Sounds a little like "Seksmisja" or Sexmission it´s called in enlish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So as I mentioned in the comments, someone was looking for a similar movie on Yahoo Answers and found it: the rather obscure 1990 Italian sci-fi film [Fuga dal paradiso](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099621/combined) (AKA Flight\Escape from Paradise). A review on IMDb fits your description of it:

> yet another film that **takes place sometime in the future after an ecological disaster** has occurred. [...] **The tale concerns two young people, Teo and Beatrice, whom live apart in an underground vault.** Their separation is not by choice however, since this vault is governed by a computer named Harry - it decides which males and females are compatible to be paired together. Of course, **Teo & Beatrice are very much in love and wish to be together**, but doubt whether Harry will give them its blessing. **The two can see each other on view screens, and neither having seen the outside world, only experience a limited controlled version of it through holographic simulations, in one scene it appears Teo is running on a tread-mill** while Beatrice is running along a field on-screen [...] Together with the help of a robot (think Buck Rogers '81 season two) **Teo and Beatrice find a way out of their designated sectors to the ruined world above.**

Here are the 2 protagonists:

[image]

Answer (score -5):

logans run In a futuristic society where reaching the age of 30 is a death sentence, a rebellious law enforcement agent goes on the run in search of Sanctuary.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074812/

Comment: OP specifically states that it is not Logan's Run.

Comment: Your Youtube link has gone dead.